# side by side images are blinkg one by one---like a sequence

Tags: jquery

I have 2 divs. Every div contains 4 buttons. 2 images are displaying side by side when click the corresponding div buttons. Ihave one more button for blinking those images. When click the button both are blinking same time.I am trying to blink them one by one. How can i do?Ty

> css

```
@keyframes blinkingFrames {
    0% {opacity: 0.00;}
    50% {opacity: 1.00;}
    100% {opacity: 0.00;}
}


}

.blinking {
    animation-name: blinkingFrames;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;

    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

jquery------------------------

```
For div-1
 $('.green-button').on('click', function() {
    $('#bar').attr('src', 'flash-green.png');

  });

For div-2
 $('.green-button1').on('click', function() {
    $('#bar1').attr('src', 'flash-green.png');
```

body------------------------

```
<img  id="ba" class="bar1" src="flash-red.png" alt="bar" >
 <img  id="ba1" class="bar1" src="flash-red.png" alt="bar" >


<button id="flash-toggle" onclick="$('.bar1').toggleClass('blinking')">
            Toggle Blinking
        </button>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want the images to blink back and forth? Both images will blink because you are calling $('.bar1').toggleClass('blinking'), and both images have the same class name ("bar1").

Comment: yes..can i call using ids?How can can i call one after another using ids?